# Не срабатывает json_decode из массива

Tags: php, json

вывожу данные с помощью echo из массива $arr_val[1] отображает {"id_event":18,"id_user":2,"id_pr":2}

пытаюсь декодировать строку с помощью json_decode($arr_val[1])
ничего не отображает.

Если я присваиваю значение новой переменной с текстом

$json = '{"id_event":18,"id_user":2,"id_pr":2}';
и декодирую строку

json_decode($json)
весь данные отображаются

В чём может быть причина???

```
$arr_event = json_decode($arr_val[1], true);
echo $arr_event->id_user . $arr_event->id_pr;
```

Comment: покажи вывод var_dump($arr_val[1]) через view-source:локалхост твой

Comment: Вы и в том и в другом случае использовали json_decode($arr_val[1], true)? Просто если в json_decode в качестве второго параметра передаете true, то результат будет в виде ассоциативного массива, и обращаться к нему надо именно как к массиву $arr_event["id_user"] и тд

Comment: да, точно, надо либо тру убрать, либо как к массиву обращаться

Comment: Пробовал и с true и без результат один. Но он же показывает когда я использую $json.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '[{"id_event":1,"id_user":1,"id_pr":1}, {"id_event":2,"id_user":2,"id_pr":2}, {"id_event":3,"id_user":3,"id_pr":3}]';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json[1]['id_event'];
```

Результат:

```
2
```

Если у Вас json в массиве, то

```
$arr_val = array('{"id_event":1,"id_user":1,"id_pr":1}', '{"id_event":2,"id_user":2,"id_pr":2}', '{"id_event":3,"id_user":3,"id_pr":3}');
foreach($arr_val as $v)
{
  $json = json_decode($v, true);
  var_dump($json);
  echo '<br>';
  echo $json['id_event'];
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Результат:

```
array(3) { ["id_event"]=> int(1) ["id_user"]=> int(1) ["id_pr"]=> int(1) } 
1
array(3) { ["id_event"]=> int(2) ["id_user"]=> int(2) ["id_pr"]=> int(2) } 
2
array(3) { ["id_event"]=> int(3) ["id_user"]=> int(3) ["id_pr"]=> int(3) } 
3
```